# Iterate through all error provider messages, and display on clickEvent ?c# winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

I am creating a `winform` projects which utilities multiple `error providers`, I have unique `errorproviders` for each `textBox`.  I'm trying to iterate through all of them and display all that are present in a `messagebox`.

So, I know I have to loop through my `controls` which I am doing correctly all my issue is that I cannot print out the specific `textboxes` which have `errors`. This is what I have, however the message Box statement is incorrect.

```
var errorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>() {epPrefConTime, epPrefConNumber, epTitle, epEmail, epAlternative, epMobile, epTown, epLandline, epHouseName, epForeName, epSurname, epPostcode, epCountry, epHouseName, epLocality, epCounty };

    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (c is SpellBox)
        {
            if (errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0))
            {

                MessageBox.Show(errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).ToString()));
                return true;
             }

        }
        else if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0))
            {
                epCountry.SetError(btn_SaveDetails, "Errors present in form, please review!!!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(e.GetError(c));
        return true;
    }
```

I'm Mapping my `errorProviders` in my my `Validating` events as follows for all 16 `textBoxes`:

```
private void txt_Forname_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (util.useUnkownEntity(txt_Forname.Text))
            {
                UnkownEntity = true;
                epForeName.SetError(txt_Forname, "Please use unknow entity!!");
                return;
            }

            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Forname.Text))
            {
                _IsValid = false;
                return;
            }

            else if (util.IsAllLetters(txt_Forname.Text))
            {
                epForeName.Clear();
                txt_Forname.Text = util.ToTitle(txt_Forname.Text);
                _IsValid = true;
                UseEntity = false;
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                epForeName.SetError(txt_Forname, "InValid Forename, please  reType!!"); _IsValid = false;
                return;
            }

        }
```

If someone could help me ascertain how to message out all of my errors provider messages or even Which text boxes the errors are in

Comment: what type is `errorProviders`? and what does it contain? how do you distinguish a textbox with error from one without error? Naming? content?

Comment: @MongZhu edited my question.   errorProviders is a List, it contains all of my error providers. and distinguish  by checking the length as so  `if (errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0))`. I Know i should use the `errorProvider1.GetError()` method just unsure how to incorperate it

Comment: so basically you are asking : how to print out all Textboxes that have content?=!

Comment: Yes thats correct, all TextBoxes which have errorproviders

Comment: it is still not really clear to me how you do the mapping from provider to textbox. So the method `GetError` receives an Textbox and returns it's content?=! or is there more to it?

Comment: @MongZhu Edited again I have used the setError Method.  If validation on the `textboxes` fails, then a `errorProvider`  is displayed next to the `Control`  which has the error.

Comment: why do you return in your for-loop after the first match? don't you want to loop through all the controls?